# How to use foreach in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I'm trying to fetch data from LinkedIn then store it in Database.

I've some problem in looping

1.In first foreach I'm inserting the data.

2.Passing the (user_id) to second insert statement.

3.Once second foreach insert the data,then again I want to go first foreach

I've written this code

```
 public void customerM()
    {
        XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
        d.LoadXml(content);
        XmlNodeList customer = d.SelectNodes("//posts/post/creator");
        foreach (XmlNode cus in customer)
        {
            user_id = cus["id"].InnerText;
            customerFirst_name = cus["first-name"].InnerText;
            customerLast_name = cus["last-name"].InnerText;
            customerName = string.Format("{0} {1}", customerFirst_name, customerLast_name);
            DbConnection.Open();
            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from mw_customer where customer_id='" + user_id + "'", DbConnection);
            OleDbDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (DbReader.Read())
            {
                count = DbReader[0].ToString();
                cnt = Convert.ToInt32(count);
                if (cnt == 0)
                {
                    DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into mw_customer(customer_id,name,first_name,last_name,user_id,cust_date,community) values('" + user_id + "','" + customerName + "','" + customerFirst_name + "','" + customerLast_name + "','" + user_id + "','" + post_timestamp + "','LinkedIn')", DbConnection);
                    DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE mw_customer set name='" + customerName + "',first_name='" + customerFirst_name + "',last_name='" + customerLast_name + "',user_id='" + user_id + "',community = 'LinkedIn',cust_date='" + post_timestamp + "' where customer_id = '" + user_id + "'", DbConnection);
                    DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            DbReader.Close();

            XmlNodeList title = d.SelectNodes("//posts/post");

            foreach (XmlNode post in title)
            {
                posts = post["title"].InnerText;
                post_id = post["id"].InnerText;
                string postTimeStamp = post["creation-timestamp"].InnerText;
                double postTimeStamp1 = Convert.ToDouble(postTimeStamp);
                DateTime post_timestamp1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Math.Round(postTimeStamp1 / 1000d)).ToLocalTime();
                post_timestamp = post_timestamp1.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");

                DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from mw_post where post_id = '" + post_id + "'", DbConnection);
                OleDbDataReader DbReader1 = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (DbReader1.Read())
                {
                    count = DbReader1[0].ToString();
                    cnt = Convert.ToInt32(count);
                    if ((cnt == 0) && (posts != ""))
                    {
                        DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into mw_post(post_id,customer_id,post,post_date,community) values('" + post_id + "','" + user_id + "','" + posts + "', '" + post_timestamp + "','LinkedIn')", DbConnection);
                        DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        if (posts.ToUpper().Contains("Personal Loan".ToUpper()))
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE mw_post set prod_id = '2',customer_id='" + user_id + "' where post = '" + posts + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        else if (posts.ToUpper().Contains("Credit Card".ToUpper()))
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE mw_post set prod_id = '1',customer_id='" + user_id + "' where post = '" + posts + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        else if (posts.ToUpper().Contains("Home Loan".ToUpper()))
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE mw_post set prod_id = '3',customer_id='" + user_id + "' where post = '" + posts + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        else if (posts.ToUpper().Contains("Car Loan".ToUpper()))
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE mw_post set prod_id = '4',customer_id='" + user_id + "' where post = '" + posts + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        else if (posts.ToUpper().Contains("Deposit".ToUpper()))
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE mw_post set prod_id = '5',customer_id='" + user_id + "' where post = '" + posts + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        else if (posts.ToUpper().Contains("Debit Card".ToUpper()))
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE mw_post set prod_id = '7',customer_id='" + user_id + "' where post = '" + posts + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE mw_post set prod_id = '6',customer_id='" + user_id + "' where post = '" + posts + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
                DbReader1.Close();
                DbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

XML file

```
  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n
  <posts total=\"1\">\n  <post>\n    
  <creation-timestamp>
  1362659632000
    </creation-timestamp>\n 
   <id>
      g-4891367-S-dfdsfd
   </id>\n    
   <title>
     dfsdfsdf
    </title>\n    
  <creator>\n
  <id>
      dfdsfsdf
   </id>\n      
  <first-name>
     dfsdfsd
    </first-name>\n     
      <last-name>
          dsfsdfd
    </last-name>\n      
     <picture-url>
         http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_zR-               8Kkl9rtYlGl1YcyCPK6tMrqDrGlCYBM60KFPQftdfsdfsdOJSfTn_tq4rYx8Svbl9K
     </picture-url>\n      
     <headline>
          dfsdfsd
    </headline>\n    
    </creator>\n 
    <comments total=\"1\">\n 
    <comment>\n 
    <creation-timestamp>
        1372061224000
    </creation-timestamp>\n
    <id>
       g-4891367-S-dsfsdfsd
    </id>\n        
    <text>
        dfsdfsd.
    </text>\n        
   <creator>\n          
   <id>
       C-dfsdfsd
   </id>\n          
   <first-name>
       dfsdfsd
   </first-name>\n  
   <last-name>
       dfsdfsd
   </last-name>\n         
   <headline>
       dsfsdsd
   </headline>\n   
   <picture-url>
              http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_OSEuUB4ZdfsdfUzsFvCLad5Y2yfY1Uqo4EXAO93Wutws8zNY9U75AECxh0metNPq6zdHm
   </picture-url>\n        
     </creator>\n        
     <creation-timestamp>
       1372061224895
    </creation-timestamp>\n        
   <relation-to-viewer>\n        
   <available-actions total=\"1\">\n
         <action>\n 
         <code>delete</code>\n        
         </action>\n          
    </available-actions>\n     
    </relation-to-viewer>\n     
   </comment>\n    
   </comments>\n   
    <likes total=\"2\">\n      
    <like>\n       
    <person>\n          
      <id>
         dfsfwe
      </id>\n          
     <first-name>
      dfsdfsd
   </first-name>\n         
  <last-name>
       dfsd
       </last-name>\n    
      <headline>
    dfsdf
       </headline>\n         
      <picture-url>
     http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0dfsdfsdda7-q79MqA-X55lrEa7- tssMzKfRilTfaJfyrYdcvX3oeLmPSf_AzuRntGlAaCl
      </picture-url>\n   
     </person>\n 
    </like>\n  <like>\n        
       <person>\n          
      <id>
      S4Er-sdjfjd
  </id>\n          
    <first-name>
      fdsfs
     </first-name>\n         
      <last-name>
      dfsdd
       </last-name>\n          
    <headline>
     sdfsdfsdfds
     </headline>\n          
 <picture-url>
      http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_kdfsdfdsfsdo
 </picture-url>\n       
      </person>\n 
       </like>\n   </likes>\n    
       <relation-to-viewer>\n
      <is-following>true</is-following>\n 
       <is-liked>false</is-liked>\n    
      <available-actions total=\"6\">\n <action>\n  
 <code>add-comment</code>\n        
        </action>\n   <action>\n  
        <code>categorize-as-job</code>\n 
 </action>\n  <action>\n  
 <code>categorize-as-promotion</code>\n  
     </action>\n <action>\n  
 <code>delete</code>\n  
 </action>\n <action>\n  
 <code>like</code>\n  
 </action>\n  <action>\n   
 <code>unfollow</code>\n 
 </action>\n </available-actions>\n 
 </relation-to-viewer>\n  </post>\n</posts>\n"
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What's wrong? Did you have any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors,in customer XmlNodeList I've 3 records,I want to pass the user_id to mw_post,same user_id is inserted for all the records in mw_post

Comment: Try to debug your program and let us know exactly on which line of code you are facing the problem? and could you please post you xml file here?

Comment: Question is poor. Try to have it more abstracted and better prepeared for viewers next time. Posting a chunk of code is sometimes a bad idea. And if I understand it correctly, you want to use something what was already used. If this falls under "repeated action" routine, then try to make method and simply call it from several places. Method can have parameters which will "tune" it to work specifically, to example, `void func(bool aftercheck = true) { ... }`, calling this before and after some check will produce different results, while method may have same repeated actions for both case inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once second foreach insert the data,then again I want to go first foreach

Since the second foreach loop is nested inside the first foreach loop, I assume  you want to reset the first foreach loop.  In this case a for loop(`for (int i = 0; i < customer.Count; i++)`) might be better, just reset the loop counter back to the initial value.

This of course is a quick fix that will require minimal re-coding.  For a proper fix the suggestion about independent methods and calling them when required or even using recursion is probably the more proper way to approach this.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable reply,can you please update your answer with code.Still I'm confusing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looping once through `"//posts/post/creator"` and then again through `"//posts/post"`. Perhaps you've just reversed your loops. Try this:

```
XmlNodeList title = d.SelectNodes("//posts/post");
foreach (XmlNode post in title)
{
    // Note: I only want creators of the current post
    XmlNodeList customer = post.SelectNodes("creator"); 
    foreach (XmlNode cus in customer)
    {
        // insert into mw_customer ... 

        // insert into mw_post ...
    }
}
```

On a side note, please look into using SQL parameters; it's far safer, as your current code is extremely vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also, I'd recommend only doing one insert, rather than an insert followed by several updates.  Finally, use `IDENTITY` columns instead of creating your keys by had with `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,but once complete second foreach I want to go first foreach

Comment: That's the way loops work. Once it done with the inner loop, it will continue with the outer loop.

Comment: Yes,I have 2 records in outer loop and 2 records in inner loop,in outer loop,I want to pass the 1st record user_id to inner loop,once it inserted then again I want to go to outer loop for fetching 2nd record,here inner loop rounding 2 times